# tkinter TreeView: disable selection highlight

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, tk-toolkit

I have a tkinter TreeView and used tags to mark multiple selected items as shown below in yellow. Unfotunately the last clicked item will always appear in blue regardless of the tag. How do I prevent the TreeView from coloring the last clicked item?

Here is the code snippet I use to select items:

```py
def on_click(self, event):
    """Set tag for selected datasets."""

    # Remove 'plotted' tag if existent
    if 'plotted' in self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['tags']:
        # FIXME: Only remove tag 'plotted'
        self.tree.item(self.tree.selection(), tags=())

    # Select only items that have no children
    elif not self.tree.get_children(self.tree.selection()):
        self.tree.item(self.tree.selection(), tags='plotted')
    self.tree.column('#0', anchor=tk.E)
```

And here is a sample how it could look like. Note you can't tell if DNTP_iDL_... is supposed to be white (b/c it has been yellow and I clicked on it to deactivate it):

[image: All entries can be selected and deselected (yellow) with the code above, but the last clicked item stays blue]

Comment: I would change the selection highlight color to yellow.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't think that would change anything since the last selected can either have the tag ("myselection", i.e. yellow) or it will not have the tag (i.e. white). However, the system will always mark the last one in on color (blue) and overwrites my tags...

Comment: Could you explain nevertheless, how that would be done? The only thing I fin in the docs is using tags, with which I'm facing the mentioned challenge.

Comment: `ttk::style map Treeview -background [list selected yellow]` .  I'm not a python person, so if one of the python/tkinter users can convert this and create an answer, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was on the wrong track with using tags for selecting multiple items.

Just use the built-in selection (with shift- or cmd-select) and then 
 `mytree.selection()` to get a list of all selected items.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's old one, but I didn't find a real answer.

After some digging - **It is possible** (not obvious but possible):

Apparently, treeview has separate systems to color - through style and through tags (use tree.tag_bind to add basic stylish things more dynamically). However, my tests showed that tags do not work from the box if you click on the item (the main problem of this question).

Here is the solution I come up with:

```py
root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style(root)
style.theme_use("clam")
style.map("Treeview",
          background=[
              ('selected', '!focus', 'yellow'),
          ])
# here is your treeview widgets and stuff
root.mainloop()
```

There could be more elegant solutions... but I didn't find one.

Hope it helps someone!

**UPDATE**

I've figured out that when you click the item and then go to another application (alt+Tab) - you will see the yellow selection.

I've solved this by changing background parameter to:

```py
# ('selected', '!focus', 'yellow'),
('selected', 'invalid', 'yellow'),
```